# how to include doc urls in result set

Tags: elasticsearch

In ElasticSearch, I am wondering how I can get back document urls as well in the search result set? Here is what I meant with some example.

Let's say I index a doc using the following curl command:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/ads/offers/1234' -d '{
  "name": "blah blah",
  "Weight":0.0001,
  ...
}'
```

Then I run a search and I want to get the document URL itself in the result set. In the above case, the document URL is the following:

```
http://localhost:9200/ads/offers/1234.
```

How can I do that? Is there a special field name for this or do I have to create some kind field to store this explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elasticsearch search response contains all piece that are needed to build this URL on the client. The record for the URL in you example will look like this:

```
"hits" : [ {
    "_index" : "ads",
    "_type" : "offers",
    "_id" : "1234",
    ...
```

If you really need to get this URL from elasticsearch you can use [script field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/script-fields.html) to combine these pieces together into a single field on the server side, although I cannot think of a legitimate scenario where it would be needed.